# Removing ?id= from URL using .HTAccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a page

```
root/pages/?id=webdesign
```

and I want to translate it into something like

```
root/pages/webdesign
```

Comment: Do you mean just for requests for root/pages or for your entire site or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: I want to remove the value of the id from the URL (remove ?id= from URL)

Comment: You have a history of poorly received questions, and if you have not hit the question ban already, you will do very shortly. If you want the privilege of asking new questions here, please read the Help Centre _before_ posting again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the prefix and replace the last part with a query string

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=
RewriteRule ^root/pages/(.+)$ /root/pages/?id=$1 [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` is needed to prevent a rewrite loop.